# Invalid Date error on moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

this is my code

```
moment("14/5/2015 5:52 am")
```

I don't know why invalid code error was come.How can i solve this issue?

Comment: to wit, it uses the new Date() if it doesn't recognize the format, but in America there's no such thing as 14/5/2015 because there's no 14th month. this is why Moment is deprecating that functionality (they mention it in the docs), i suggest you solve it by trying to use the new Date() to make the date, and then pass that in to moment

Comment: Also `new Date("14/5/2015 5:52 am")` gave this same issue

Comment: yes, as that is to be expected, you can't use new Date("14/5/2015") for the same reason why moment fails, what i meant by using new date is to, just becareful in the next version of moment(here's the link to the issues: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Daemedeor

I found the answer from your comment.

Now i have changed my date format to Month first then date

Like something below,

```
moment("5/14/2015 5:52 am")// Now its' working.
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

For this case, you need to supply the format too:

`var m = moment("14/5/2015 5:52 am", 'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a')`

Then it works as expected:

```
> m.date()
  14
> m.month()
  4
> m.year()
  2015
```

Comment: Also i have did this. but does not worked, anyway i have found my answer :+1

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought you wanted to use a custom format.